# Problem hiding keyboard when scrolling to an EditText field

Tags: java, android, kotlin, layout, kotlin-android-extensions

I have a `ScrollView` that contains several `EditText` and `AutoCompleteTextView` views. I'd like to hide the keyboard if the user scrolls or taps out of the text box.

So I added this to my `Fragments` `onViewCreated()`

```
myScrollView?.viewTreeObserver?.addOnScrollChangedListener {
            hideKeyboard()
        }
```

The problem is, when I start scrolling the keyboard hides, BUT when I click an `EditText` or `AutoCompleteTextView`, the view starts to scroll to that field to show the keyboard, but because, the scrollview has  the `addOnScrollChangedListener` it hides the keyboard. And the view just jumps back and forth with hiding and showing the keyboard.

**What is the correct way to handle this scenario?**

The `hideKeyboard()` comes from an extension class

```
fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
    hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
}

fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
    val inputMethodManager = getSystemService(AppCompatActivity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
}

fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
    view?.let {
        activity?.hideKeyboard(it)
    }
}
```